# Error setting variable to Null Value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to write a module in a form that auto-fills an ExpiryDate control based on a user-input IssueDate control and a DaysValid field in a related table. If there is no data in DaysValid, it treats the record as one that never expires, and leaves ExpiryDate blank.

Here's the module as it currently stands:

```
Private Sub IssueDate_AfterUpdate()

If Not IsNull(IssueDate) Then
    Dim DysVld As Integer
    DysVld = DLookup("[DaysValid]", "tblInduction", "[ID] = " & Me.Induction)
        If IsNull(DysVld) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ExpiryDate.Value = DysVld + IssueDate
End If

End Sub
```

If there is no value in tblInduction.DaysValid, I get run time error 94 - invalid use of Null. From this I infer that I'm not allowed to set a variable to a Null value... I could put the following if clause earlier, but that seems more cumbersome than should be necessary. What's best practice on dealing with this? An error handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the error.

Only variant variable can hold Null. The DysVld variable is declared as integer. Either declare it as Variant or change code.

```
DysVld = Nz(DLookup("[DaysValid]", "tblInduction", "[ID] = " & Me.Induction),0)
If DysVld <> 0
```

Comment: AH! The Nz function! that'll fix it for me. Thanks!